# Get a list of azure subscription, resource groups, resources and status

Tags: azure, automation, azure-cloud-services

I'm figuring on how do I automate my daily reports on azure resources which will send through outlook on a daily basis. I am beginner to this MS Azure.

An excel sheet that contains a list of subscriptions and within it are the resource group and its resources. An example of status would be Storage Account: **Available** **256 GB** capacity / Virtual machine: **Running** **256GB** available. With this list I would send an email to the relevant recipients. (Any suggestions on sending an email with an excel sheet at a certain time e.g 9am and 6pm)

Comment: look into the Azure CLI or Rest API, those are two options for getting information about resources in Azure.  This is a big task so start small and building it out as you proceed.

Comment: maybe i'll start with gather the resources and its status using azure cli/rest api/scripts first. Any links that i could refer to help me out with this?

Answer (score 0):

*I can list the all azure subscriptions, resource groups and resources using Azure cli*

*To get the all subscriptions which are there use the below command*

```
Get-AzureRmSubscription
```

[image]

*To get the list of resource groups and its subscription and the status*

```
Get-AzureRmResourceGroup
```

[image]

*I can also list the resource for particular region, resource group and name*

```
az resource list --query "[].{resourceGRP:resourceGroup,name:name,location:location}"
```

[image]

*To get the all resources list under the resource group*

```
az resource list --resource-group  Alldemorg --output table
```

[image]

*For more information Refer this [Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/resource?view=azure-cli-latest)*